# Logical Query Processing: How the select is before the order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using T-SQL and in the book T-SQL Fundamentals of Itzik Ben Gan, he said that Select clause is processed logically before the Order by clause.

I agree on this, but I want to know how the select is processed before the ORDER BY, when the TOP is in the select and it needs the result of the order by first?

Comment: "processed before" can mean: I need those fields, I need to restrict top top 5 entries, I need to join those tables, I need to order by thisandthat. Logical processig. providing an execution plan that includes all that.

Comment: [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630346/Understanding-how-SQL-Server-executes%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-a-query) -HTH ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without rewriting a lot of what's already been written before:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql

Short version: Imagine that SQL Server creates virtual tables during query execution. Those tables and their values are passed, step-by-step, through a logical process that determines your end result. The goal is to "fetch" the minimum number of rows from the beginning, and thereby filter out as few rows as possible. After all, why "fetch" 100,000 rows if you only want to see 2?

In the case of a `TOP` clause, you're only going to **see** those `TOP x` rows, but that doesn't mean that they are the only rows that SQL Server checked during the query execution.

On the contrary - if you're looking for the `TOP x` rows by some column value, then clearly SQL Server needs to make sure that it first analyzes the values for that column, orders them accordingly, and can only then present you with the `TOP x` rows. This is why having proper indexes can make such a difference when executing these sorts of queries.

This is very different from the `WHERE` clause, which can happen earlier on, because a value either = X, or it doesn't; so when scanning a table, SQL Server can know for every single row whether or not that row should be included in the final result set. With a `TOP` clause, this is not necessarily the case. Halfway through the query process, it doesn't necessarily know if there are more unread rows that should be included in that `TOP` or not - it can only know once the rows have been selected in accordance with all previous conditions, then ordered by your `ORDER BY` clause. Finally, it knows which rows should be in those `TOP x` rows you asked for.

Notice that in Microsoft's documentation, they explicitly state that the logical processing order can change from query to query, especially in extenuating circumstances (i.e., a `VIEW` that uses `CONVERT()`, or depending upon the indexes for a given table.)